# Hair doesn't follow vertex group

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

Today I wanted to put some hair on my character. I used weight paint to make a vertex group. The hair particle system doesn't seem to follow the vertex group, though.

[image]

Can anybody help?

(I'm sorry for all the silly questions I've asked so far. But thanks for the answers!)

Edit: I've found the answer. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

the one that you posted shows that you created a vertex group, the next step is to assign the hair particles in that vertex group.

particles -> vertex groups -> density -> and then scroll down to select the vertex group that you created

[image]