# Assign Particle System to parts of a mesh

Tags: materials, particles

In the materials slot their is an "assign" button, is there anything like this for particle systems? But more specifically is there a way to assign a different material to a different part of a mesh. Now finally how do I keep a particle system off part of my mesh entirely? For example: 
[image: bird] 
I want the blue and black to be the same particle system, but different colors, the orange to be a different particle system and no system on the legs.

Comment: You can use vertex groups or weights.

Comment: @cegaton could you explain a little more, I see the vertex groups tab under particle systems and I have vertex groups on my bird(mainly from the armature) but I don't know what to do once there

Comment: See https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html and https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/vertexgroups.html

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19375/placement-of-hairhair-particles-ignores-weight-paint-and-vertex-groups and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46573/why-do-my-particles-grow-outside-the-density-vertex-group and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/how-to-control-hair-particle-position/6251#6251 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36249/hair-doesnt-follow-vertex-group and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40270/how-to-make-forest-with-different-types-of-trees/40273#40273